# Event handling with async await in Python

Tags: python, async-await, tkinter

Recently, I had to write a code to classify and rename lots of image files based on their content. So, I wrote a Python script which displays all those images as a slideshow to the me, and I can classify and rename them with one button click, instead of renaming every file manually.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
 ---rootDir
    +--dir1
    |  +--subDir
    |  +--imgx1.png
    |  +--imgx2.png
    |  |
    +--dir2
    |  +--subDir
    |  +--imgy1.png
    |  +--imgy2.png
    |  |
```

This is the script I wrote, and it is working correctly.

```
import util    # local config file
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Event
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

os.chdir(util.rootPath)

def iterateImage():
    global dirIter, imgIter
    global currDir, currImg
    
    try:
        currImg = next(imgIter)
    except StopIteration:
        try:
            currDir = next(dirIter)
        except StopIteration:
            exit()
        
        imgIter = iter(os.listdir(currDir))
        iterateImage()
        return

    if not currImg.endswith('.png'):
        iterateImage()
        return

def showImage():
    global im

    iterateImage()
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fr'{currDir}\{currImg}'))
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.create_image(400, 400, anchor='center', image=im)
    root.title(currImg)
    root.update()

def onKeyEvent(event:Event):
    if event.keysym == 'n':
        emo = 'neutral'
    elif event.keysym == 'h':
        emo = 'happy'
    elif event.keysym == 's':
        emo = 'sad'
    elif event.keysym == 'a':
        emo = 'angry'
    elif event.keysym == 'q':
        showImage()
        return
    else:
        return
    
    newName = fr'pic_{currDir}_{emo}.png'
    try:
        os.rename(fr'{currDir}\{currImg}', fr'{currDir}\{newName}')
    except FileExistsError as e:
        print('File Already Exists:', e.filename, e.filename2)
    showImage()

def initSlideShow():
    global root, canvas
    global dirIter, imgIter
    
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
    canvas.pack()

    dirIter = iter(util.dirList)
    imgIter = iter(())
    
    showImage()
    root.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', onKeyEvent)
    root.mainloop()

currDir:str
currImg:str

print('As soon as you continue, you will be shown list of pictures.')
print('Classify them accordingly into emotion categories.')
print('n -> Neutral')
print('h -> Happy')
print('s -> Sad')
print('a -> Angry')
print('q -> SKIP')
print('Press ENTER to start slideshow')
input()
print('NOTE: In some cases you may have to manually bring the slideshow window into focus.')
print()
initSlideShow()
```

But I feel this is harder to maintain than it should be. So, is it possible to modify and restructure this code using async-await feature of Python to make it more managable? In particular, is it possible to write the above as this:

```
import util    # local config file
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Event
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

os.chdir(util.rootPath)

async def slideShow():
    global im, renamed
    global currDir, currImg

    for currDir in util.dirList:
        for currImg in os.listdir(currDir):
            if not currImg.endswith('.png'):
                continue

            im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fr'{currDir}\{currImg}'))
            canvas.delete('all')
            canvas.create_image(400, 400, anchor='center', image=im)
            root.title(currImg)
            root.update()
            renamed = False
            await ...    # till renamed becomes True

def onKeyEvent(event:Event):
    global renamed

    if event.keysym == 'n':
        emo = 'neutral'
    elif event.keysym == 'h':
        emo = 'happy'
    elif event.keysym == 's':
        emo = 'sad'
    elif event.keysym == 'a':
        emo = 'angry'
    elif event.keysym == 'q':
        renamed = True
        return
    else:
        return
    
    newName = fr'pic_{currDir}_{emo}.png'
    try:
        os.rename(fr'{currDir}\{currImg}', fr'{currDir}\{newName}')
    except FileExistsError as e:
        print('File Already Exists:', e.filename, e.filename2)
    renamed = True

def initSlideShow():
    global root, canvas
    
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
    canvas.pack()

    root.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', onKeyEvent)
    slideShow()
    root.mainloop()

print('As soon as you continue, you will be shown list of pictures.')
print('Classify them accordingly into emotion categories.')
print('n -> Neutral')
print('h -> Happy')
print('s -> Sad')
print('a -> Angry')
print('q -> SKIP')
print('Press ENTER to start slideshow')
input()
print('NOTE: In some cases you may have to manually bring the slideshow window into focus.')
print()
initSlideShow()
```

Mainly two things I want to change:
*I manually handling iterators* vs *For loop handling iterators for me*.
*Calling showImage function after every rename* vs *Calling slideShow function only once and it itself resuming after every rename*.